# Nginx | 2 Domains (1x Node App, 1x Static HTML) on one server

Tags: html, node.js, nginx, dns, host

I am having trouble running one node app and one static page (just html) on two seperate domains at the same time. No matter what I tried the static domain gets always redirected to the node app (on port 3000)

Here are the "sites-available" files :

Node App :

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;


server_name www.domain1.com domain1.com;

# and redirect to the https host (declared below)
return 301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    ssl on;
    # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';


    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

And the static one :

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;


   #server_name www.domain2.com domain2.com;

   root /var/www/html/domain2;
   index index.html index.htm;


   return 301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {

   listen [::]:443 ssl;
   listen 443 ssl;

   root /var/www/html/domain2;

   index index.html index.htm;

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

The default config file is empty. Any help/hint would be greatly appreciated.

It worked fine until I generated a Let's encrypt certificate for domain2, put both domains in seperate configs and removed the default.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you installed the symlink to `sites-enabled`?

Comment: Hey Richard, thanks for the comment. Yes the symlink is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have no `server_name` directive in your static domain configuration. As a result, the request is always caught by your default server block, which appears to be your node app.

See for details:

- [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)
- [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)
- [Configuring HTTPS servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

Comment: VBart, thank you very much! Problem solved! Thanks again!